# install python3.6 on amazonlinux docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, python-3.6, amazon-linux

I have been experimenting to create a docker image with python3.6 based on amazonlinux.
So far, I have not been very successful. I use

```
docker run -it amazonlinux
```

to start an interactive docker terminal. Inside the terminal, I run "yum install python36" and see the following error message. Note that I copied this step was from an old amazonlinux based Dockerfile. This Dockerfile used to work. So I suspend the error I see below is due to amazon updated their docker linux image

```
bash-4.2# yum install python36
Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn2-core       | 2.4 kB  00:00:00     
No package python36 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I have tried to add a python3.6 repo by following this post
https://janikarhunen.fi/how-to-install-python-3-6-1-on-centos-7 however, it still gives the same error when I run

```
yum install python36u
```

Is there any way to add python3.6 to amazonlinux base layer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/RealSalmon/docker-amazonlinux-python/blob/master/Dockerfile) based on amazon Linux and having python version is `PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.4`.

Or you can work with your existing one like

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.4
ARG BOTO3_VERSION=1.6.3
ARG BOTOCORE_VERSION=1.9.3
ARG APPUSER=app

RUN yum -y update &&\
    yum install -y shadow-utils findutils gcc sqlite-devel zlib-devel \
                   bzip2-devel openssl-devel readline-devel libffi-devel && \
    groupadd ${APPUSER} && useradd ${APPUSER} -g ${APPUSER} && \
    cd /usr/local/src && \
    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar -xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && make && make altinstall && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/src/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}* && \
    yum remove -y shadow-utils audit-libs libcap-ng && yum -y autoremove && \
    yum clean all
```

But better to clone the repo and make your own image form that.

Answer (score 4):

There is now a far easier answer to this question thanks to aws 'extras'. Now this will work:

```
amazon-linux-extras install python3
```

Comment: Note that this won't install the same python36 dependencies as may be expected (e.g., `python36-devel` is still entirely unavailable).  Any other packages expecting `python36` installed on the system will not find it.

Answer (score 0):

I too had similiar issue for docker.

yum install docker

Loaded plugins: ovl, priorities
amzn2-core                                                                                                                                                                                  | 3.7 kB  00:00:00
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do

instead yum I used amazon-linux-extras, it worked

## amazon-linux-extras install docker